# jQuery EasySlider, no % as width?

Tags: jquery, easyslider

I'm trying to use jQuery EasySlider to carousel, however, when I specify a number in percentage for the width of the div container, the container fails to deliver content.

Am I to assume that it is incapable of dealing with percentages?

Comment: Are you planning to resize the surrounding DIV, and the EasySLider to follow suit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the container `div` have *floating children*? If true, that's why the div doesn't show any content (floating elements are taken out of the document flow and thus out of the parent element, which in turn will collapse to 0 width when there are no no-floating children).

Comment: What do you mean by floating children? Div -> ul -> li

Comment: CSS floating. Floating can be set to left, right or none. It is often used for styling. For more info, this should help: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/. Remember: div's can float, ul's can float and even li's can float.

Answer (score 0):

In EasySlider 1.7 It should work just fine. The relevant code in the plugin is:

```
var w = $("li", obj).width();
```

.width() in jQuery returns the value in pixels even if it is specified in the CSS as a percentage. Whether you specify percentage or pixels, it's effectively the same.

Which version of EasySlider are you using?

Comment: I'm using 1.7 :)
http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

Answer (score 0):

Use this ancient Math equation:

```
function getPercentage(percent, original)
{
    return ((percent/100) * original))|0;
}
```

Customize the code as you want, It just gets the desired percentage of any number!.

Comment: That will work for one time, but doesn't if the div changes its size.